# iOS gamekit, card game players, & GKVoiceChatService

Tags: xcode, gamekit, gksession, audiosession

I'm working on a card game for iOS. I'm thinking game center integration is something I want to be leaning towards, but in terms of a card game, I'm not exactly sure what that would entail for the individual players. From the Apple class reference, it seems that`GKPlayer` is what I want to be working with, but I also have my own player class that I think I'm going to need just to deal with card hands. I'm wonderring if my Player class should have a `GKPlayer` object in it or if that would be the wrong way to be going about it.

I'm also wonderring about the game center voice chat (I know this sounds completely unrelated to card games, but bear with me). I've not seen it implemented, so I'm not entirely sure how it works. Basically what I would need would be for it to be able to connect 4-10 players and to just be a voice chat sort of thing. It seems like the sort of thing that would need to display something on screen which I want to avoid. How would that work?

Comment: +1, Good question, but there are way too many sub questions. Hopefully someone will take time answer. Next time just break it into multiple question for quick response. :)

Answer (score 0):

#### First Question's Answer :

Q: Player class should have a GKPlayer?

A: Well, that would be considered to be a good design. Because, a GKPlayer object will let you know the details of connected player who are currently participating in a game. However, It would be better if you can use the subclass of GKPlayer named GKLocalPlayer. So in that way you maintain an authenticity, one player with one device.

For more information on multiplayer game : [Click here!](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Users/Users.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH8-SW6)

It seems like we can only have peer to peer voice chat. (But wait for an experts, to share more details with their own hacks!)